# I am having trouble getting an enter to go to app when I send test to another application

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am trying to sendkeys to another app. I have succeeded in getting window pointer. I am sending text to the app. I do not have a working solution in order to send the {ENTER} key (or ^M).

I have search for information on web. Most of the information I am finding is old.

```
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string acStr = "";
            AcWinCheck();
            int x = 0;
            foreach (var item in logToSend)
               {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                SendKeys.SendWait(item); 
                SendKeys.SendWait("^m"); 
                // I can not seem to get a return added
                // SendKeys.SendWait(" {ENTER } ");
                SendKeys.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
        }

     readonly string[] logToSend = new string[3]
        {
            "/log PropDump.txt",
            "/PropertyDump",
            "/log"
        };
```

My lines of text and running on to each other.Ex:
/log PropDump.txt  /propertydump /log is the way it is coming out

... which what I want is:

/log PropDump.txt

/propertydump

/log

Comment: How about   Environment.NewLine ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it seemed to make no difference.                 SendKeys.SendWait($"{item}{NewLine}");

Comment: You you have a space in `{ENTER }`?

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Thomas. That did not cure my ailment!

Comment: Have you tried `PostMessage`?